# Extract Clojure map entries with a pattern into a list of maps?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, functional-programming

I have a map like this (with 1 or more items mixed together):

```
{:item_name_1 "Great Deal"
 :item_options_2 "blah: 2"
 :item_name_2 "Awesome Deal" 
 :item_options_1 "foo: 3" 
 :item_quantity_1 "1"
 :item_price_2 "9.99" 
 :item_price_1 "9.99"
 :itemCount "2"}
```

And I want to make it into this:

```
[{:item_quantity "1"
  :item_options "blah" 
  :item_name "Great Deal"
  :item_price "9.99"}
 {:item_name "Awesome Deal" 
  :item_options "foo"
  :item_quantity "1" 
  :item_price "9.99"}]
```

So, I want to separate them out by the item keys:

```
(def item-keys [:item_name :item_options :item_price :item_quantity])
```

I'm guessing I could somehow use `map` or `walk` but I can't see what to do -- I'm pretty new to Clojure.

I'd start with

```
(defn parse-items
  [mixed-map]
  (let [num-items (Integer/parseInt (:itemCount mixed-map))]
    (into []
      (do-something mixed-map))))
```

Comment: The heart of the question is, "how do I extract N hash-maps out of 1 hash-map?". `(name :item_price_1)` will give the string form, #"" regex.. somehow use `into []`...

Comment: Thanks for all the detailed answers! I'm still studying and evaluating them. I ended up doing something a bit different with more separate functions,  based on help from @seanomlor offline which I'll post and will choose the most useful (to me) answer here soon.

Comment: Here's what I settled on for now.
https://gist.github.com/sventech/cdc4f0a662192980dd03

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the problem can be redefined as follows.

1. Group key-value pairs in given maps by keyword suffixes.
2. Create maps per grouping and pour them into a new vector.

If these assumptions are correct, here is my solution.

First, define a helper function, called `kv->skv`, which convert an original key-value pair (`[k v]`) into a vector of a suffix and a modified key-value pair (`[suffix [k' v]`).

```
user> (def items {:item_name_1 "Great Deal"
                  :item_options_2 "blah: 2"
                  :item_name_2 "Awesome Deal" 
                  :item_options_1 "foo: 3" 
                  :item_quantity_1 "1"
                  :item_price_2 "9.99" 
                  :item_price_1 "9.99"
                  :itemCount "2"})
#'user/items

user> (defn- kv->skv
        [[k v]]
        (let [[_ k' s] (re-find #"(.+)_(\d+)" (name k))]
          [s [k' v]]))
#'user/kv->skv

user> (def items' (map kv->skv items))
#'user/items'

user> (clojure.pprint/pprint items')
(["1" ["item_name" "Great Deal"]]
 ["2" ["item_options" "blah: 2"]]
 ["2" ["item_name" "Awesome Deal"]]
 ["1" ["item_options" "foo: 3"]]
 ["1" ["item_quantity" "1"]]
 ["2" ["item_price" "9.99"]]
 ["1" ["item_price" "9.99"]]
 [nil [nil "2"]])
nil
```

Then, filter items using the item keys.

```
user> (def item-keys #{:item_name :item_options :item_price :item_quantity})
#'user/item-keys

user> (def items-filtered (filter (comp item-keys keyword first second) items'))
#'user/items-filtered

user> (clojure.pprint/pprint items-filtered)
(["1" ["item_name" "Great Deal"]]
 ["2" ["item_options" "blah: 2"]]
 ["2" ["item_name" "Awesome Deal"]]
 ["1" ["item_options" "foo: 3"]]
 ["1" ["item_quantity" "1"]]
 ["2" ["item_price" "9.99"]]
 ["1" ["item_price" "9.99"]])
nil
```

Second, group modified key-value pairs by suffixes using the `group-by` function.

```
user> (def groupings (group-by first items-filtered))
#'user/groupings

user> (clojure.pprint/pprint groupings)
{"1"
 [["1" ["item_name" "Great Deal"]]
  ["1" ["item_options" "foo: 3"]]
  ["1" ["item_quantity" "1"]]
  ["1" ["item_price" "9.99"]]],
 "2"
 [["2" ["item_options" "blah: 2"]]
  ["2" ["item_name" "Awesome Deal"]]
  ["2" ["item_price" "9.99"]]]}
nil
```

And convert groupings into maps.

```
user> (def what-you-want (->> (vals groupings)
                              (map #(->> %
                                         (map second)
                                         (into {})))))
#'user/what-you-want

user> (clojure.pprint/pprint what-you-want)
({"item_name" "Great Deal",
  "item_options" "foo: 3",
  "item_quantity" "1",
  "item_price" "9.99"}
 {"item_options" "blah: 2",
  "item_name" "Awesome Deal",
  "item_price" "9.99"})
nil
```

Finally, integrate these steps into a function.

```
(defn extract-items
  [items item-keys]
  (let [kv->skv (fn
                  [[k v]]
                  (let [[_ k' s] (re-find #"(.+)_(\d+)" (name k))]
                    [s [k' v]]))]
    (->> items
         (map kv->skv)
         (filter (comp item-keys keyword first second))
         (group-by first)
         vals
         (map #(->> %
                    (map second)
                    (into {}))))))
```

It works.

```
user> (clojure.pprint/pprint (extract-items items item-keys))
({"item_name" "Great Deal",
  "item_options" "foo: 3",
  "item_quantity" "1",
  "item_price" "9.99"}
 {"item_options" "blah: 2",
  "item_name" "Awesome Deal",
  "item_price" "9.99"})
nil
```

I hope this step-by-step approach help you.

Comment: Thanks for the time you put into the explanation! It helps a lot to see the process.

Answer (score 1):

A complete and straightforward solution is:

```
(->> item-map
     (keep (fn [[k v]]
             (let [[_ name id] (re-find #"(.+)_(\d+)$" (name k))]
               (if id
                 [[(dec (Integer/parseInt id)) (keyword name)] v]))))
     (sort-by ffirst)
     (reduce (partial apply assoc-in) []))
```

If you wish to allow non-consecutive ids or don't know in advance whether they are 0-indexed you can modify the algorithm like this:

```
(->> item-map
     (keep (fn [[k v]]
             (let [[_ name id] (re-find #"(.+)_(\d+)$" (name k))]
               (if id
                 [id [(keyword name) v]]))) )
     (sort-by first)
     (partition-by first)
     (map #(->> %
                (map second)
                (into {}))))
```

Notice that loose input requirements as this algorithm allows remove the guarantee of lossless transformation (assuming no unnumbered keys except `:item-count` are expected). E. g. a backwards transformation algorithm can't be expected to produce an equal value to `item-map` from the result again.

I left out the filtering of `item-keys` for clarity, since it is a separate concern. You can integrate it into both algorithms by defining `item-keys` as a hash set and changing the lambda to `keep` as follows:

```
(let [[_ name id] (re-find #"(.+)_(\d+)$" (name k))
      k (-> name keyword item-keys)]
  (if (and id k)
    ;; ...
```

Comment: You might want to replace `(comp first first)` with `ffirst`.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `$` at the end of the regex to make sure the number is in the suffix position?

Answer (score 0):

If using regex is not mandatory and assuming the "suffixes" in `mixed-map` keys are numbers from 1 to `num-items`, the problem can be solved in a straight-forward way.

There should be as many hash-maps in the result as there are items. We have `num-items` so we can map over the range from 1 to `num-items` At each step we can create one hash-map for the current item number. To create each individual hash-map, we can map over `item-keys` and turn each item key into a map entry. The key in the map entry is the item-key itself. The value comes from the `mixed-map`. We just need a way to create keys for the `mixed-map` from an item number and the item key. Along the way we should not forget that not every item has every key, so we need to deal with nil values. Putting it all together, we have the following.

```
(def items {:item_name_1 "Great Deal"
            :item_options_2 "blah: 2"
            :item_name_2 "Awesome Deal" 
            :item_options_1 "foo: 3" 
            :item_quantity_1 "1"
            :item_price_2 "9.99" 
            :item_price_1 "9.99"
            :itemCount "2"})

(def item-keys [:item_name :item_options :item_price :item_quantity])

(defn parse-items
   [mixed-map]
   (let [num-items (Integer/parseInt (:itemCount mixed-map))
         all-item-numbers (range 1 (inc num-items))
         mixed-map-key (fn [n k] (keyword (str (name k) "_" n)))
         map-entry (fn [n k] 
                     (when-let [v (mixed-map (mixed-map-key n k))] 
                       [k v]))
         map-entries (fn [n] (map #(map-entry n %) item-keys))]
     (mapv #(into {} (map-entries %)) all-item-numbers)))

(clojure.pprint/pprint (parse-items items))

; => [{:item_name "Great Deal",
; =>   :item_options "foo: 3",
; =>   :item_price "9.99",
; =>   :item_quantity "1"}
; =>  {:item_name "Awesome Deal",
; =>   :item_options "blah: 2",
; =>   :item_price "9.99"}]
; => nil
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is most similar with what I ended up doing, but I wanted to reward the work @tnoda did in explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
(require '[clojure.string :as s])

(defn key-and-index
  "Given a string like 'foo_bar_7' return ['foo_bar' 7]"
  [s]
  (let [segments (s/split s #"_")
        k (s/join "_" (drop-last segments))
        index (read-string (last segments))]
      [k index]))

(defn item-map
  "Reducing fn: given an accumulated nested map of index:key:val,
  and a current item, parse the current item into the same shape
  and add it to the map."
  [m [old-key v]]
  (let [[k i] (key-and-index (name old-key))]
    (if (not (empty? k)) ; drop extraneous input data
      (assoc-in m [i k] v)
      m)))

(vals (reduce item-map {} items))
```

(like the other posted answers, it ignores your specified transformation from "foo:3" and "blah: 2" to "foo" and "blah", which in my opinion should be handled separately.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm worried about your data.

- We don't need `:itemCount`.
- The numbers ought surely to be numbers, not strings.
- If, as the name suggests, there might be several `:item_options_...`
  for each item, the value ought to be a map, not a string.

So your data ought to look like this:

```
(def data {:item_name_1 "Great Deal"
           :item_options_2 {blah: 2}
           :item_name_2 "Awesome Deal" 
           :item_options_1 {foo: 3}
           :item_quantity_1 1
           :item_price_2 9.99
           :item_price_1 9.99})
```

Now we follow more or less the same course as [@tnoda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29983412/1562315), with one or two refinements.

Each key in `data` contains

- an *identifier* for the thing the entry applies to and
- an *attribute* of the thing.

To make our solution generally useful, it will take a *function argument* that splits the key into these two aspects. For your data, a suitable function is:

```
(defn dissect [kw]
  (let [text (name kw)
        point (.lastIndexOf text "_")]
    ((comp
      (partial mapv keyword)
      (juxt #(subs % 0 point) #(subs % (inc point)))
      name)
     kw)))

(dissect :item_name_1)
;[:item_name :1]
```

Now we need to classify your data accordingly. I suggest doing it like this:

```
(defn classify [cracker m]
  (->> m
       (map (juxt (comp cracker key) val)) ; crack the keys into [id attribute] pairs
       (group-by (comp second first))      ; group by id
       vals                                ; discard the id keys
       (mapv #(->> % (map (juxt ffirst second)) (into {}))) ; assemble the maps
       ))
```

The comments explain what is going on at each stage in the cascade of functions. You can comment out all the functions in the cascade, then re-introduce them one at a time from the top. This will show you what each line accomplishes.

Let's apply the function to our `data`:

```
(classify dissect data)
;[{:item_name "Great Deal", :item_options {:foo 3}, :item_quantity 1, :item_price 9.99} {:item_options {:blah 2}, :item_name "Awesome Deal", :item_price 9.99}]
```

It works! Yippee!

If you want to stick with your old data, you have to weed out the rogue `:itemCount` key:

```
(def old-data {:item_name_1 "Great Deal"
               :item_options_2 "blah: 2"
               :item_name_2 "Awesome Deal" 
               :item_options_1 "foo: 3" 
               :item_quantity_1 "1"
               :item_price_2 "9.99" 
               :item_price_1 "9.99"
               :itemCount "2"})

(classify dissect (dissoc old-data :itemCount))
;[{:item_name "Great Deal", :item_options "foo: 3", :item_quantity "1", :item_price "9.99"} {:item_options "blah: 2", :item_name "Awesome Deal", :item_price "9.99"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Thumbnail. I'm parsing the output of SimpleCart(js) which relies on HTML localStorage. I think they used some odd data structures to support an old poly-fill for non-compliant web browsers. These days a JSON document might make more sense than POST/GET of forms...
Anyway, `:item_options` is a single string with more name/value pair data embedded.